# Can't explicitly instantiate a templated class

Tags: c++, template-classes

In "header.h"

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    void func();
};
```

In "Source2.cpp"

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::func()
{
    T a = 5;
    std::cout << a;;
}
```

In "Source1.cpp"

```
#include "Header.h"

template struct Foo<int>;

int main()
{
    Foo<int> b;
    b.func();
}
```

Linker error: LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Foo::func(void)" (?func@?$Foo@H@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main

Is this not the right way to explicitly instantiate a class?

Comment: are you compiling correctly?

Comment: the definition of *func* must be in the header file, not only its declaration

Comment: @bruno I thought explicit instantiation is a method you can use to not have the definition in the header file

Comment: You need to put the explicit instantiations after the method implementation in `Source2.cpp`.

Comment: @cigien I see, why is it not working the way I have it?

Comment: Think about what happens when you compile the TU containing `Source2.cpp`. There is no instantiation of the method anywhere, so it simply never gets generated. Also, this makes the explicit instantiation in `Source1.cpp` redundant.

Comment: @Zebrafish look at my answer (hopping it is clear for you)

Comment: @bruno But it doesn't have to go into the header file, there are methods to have the definitions in a cpp file, one is explicit instantiation

Comment: @cigien If I explicitly instantiate like I did in "Source1.cpp" doesn't it create an int version of the struct in "Source1.cpp"?

Comment: Yes, it does, but the `int` instantiation of the struct doesn't have a definition of the method.

Comment: @cigien I see. Why does it only create the int version of the function if the class is instantiated in the same cpp that the function is defined in? I expected that by explicitly instantiating the class in "Source1.cpp" that the function in "Source2.cpp" is instantiated, to int, and that the linker would find it in that cpp.

Comment: No, when compiling `Source2.cpp` it's as if `Source1.cpp` *doesn't exist at all*. No code in `Source1.cpp` is involved in the compilation of `Source2.cpp`, so the compiler *couldn't* know that an `int` instantiation is needed by some other TU (it's certainly not going to instantiate any thing more than it needs to). So the linker never gets the appropriate definition to link.

Comment: [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/B1ELEPOjI) with `template struct Foo<int>;` in Source2.cpp

Answer (score -1):

The definition of the template methods must be placed in the header file with the associated class allowing the compiler to 'expand' them (I use 'expand' to simplify, a template method is not a macro)

so in Header.h :

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    void func();
};

template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::func()
{
    T a = 5;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

In "Source1.cpp"

```
#include "Header.h"

template struct Foo<int>;

int main()
{
    Foo<int> b;
    b.func();
}
```

Compilation and execution (a `std::cout << std::endl;` is missing to be sure to flush and write a newline) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ Source1.cpp 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
5pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Do not be afraid of 'multiple' definitions of *func* because you use the same instantiation in several files, the compiler/linker manages that for you